# Shipping Amount for different payment method in magento

Tags: magento

how to apply different shipping amount for each payment method in magento? Now i am currently using two payment methods.

1) credit cart 
2) Cash on delivery.

When customer selecting credit cart payment method shipping price is free. 
and when customer selecting Cash on delivery payment method shipping price is 100. 
FYI : my default shipping amount is 100.

Can anyone explain me briefly?

Thank 
Prakash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the payment method is chosen based on the shipping method, so you can't change the shipping after choosing a payment method.

One possibility is to offer to different shipping method which restrict the payment methods after selecting.

I've created a magento module which does this, feel free to take a look on the sourcecode how it restricts payment methods based on shipping rates. This is the way I'd go.

https://github.com/thebod/Thebod_Shippingrates

Comment: hai bod your moduele is really very useful for me.i wish very thankful to you.

Comment: Thanks! I'm observing payment_method_is_active to restrict the payment methods, I hope it helps you improving your store :)

Comment: Hai bod.The shipping amount did not show in customer order details page in frontend.Can you help me? What i will do now?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a **Promotion** rule with the ***Shopping Cart Price Rule*** for specific Payment Methods.

[image: Shopping Cart Price Rule for specific Payment Method]